# Not too expensive vs affordable

Tags: phrases

I'm building a website and I need to choose between 'not too expensive' and 'affordable'. The sentence:

> Reliable, stable, secure, great support and of course not too expensive!

or

> Reliable, stable, secure, great support and of course affordable!

Which one is the best?

Comment: The better choice depends on what you want to say. So what do you want to say? The options mean different things.

Comment: @MattЭллен Well, I want to say it's not too expensive :p

Comment: Great! So you have your answer.

Comment: I'd say that in general usage they're pretty close in meaning. 'Inexpensive' is more attractive than either to my ears (though then the warning bells would chime in – _trust a salesman??_) 'Great value' is the usual sales patter.

Comment: Seriously though, @WilliamDavidEdwards, something that is not too expensive might not be affordable and something that is affordable might be expensive. What are you trying to promote?

Comment: e.g. are you trying to promote how [product] is going to be within someone's budget, or are you trying to say that [product] is cheap?

Comment: Since you're trying to sell something, "affordable" is much better. The reason is that the presence of "expensive" in "not too expensive" is subconsciously glass-half-empty, while affordable is subconsciously glass-half-full

Comment: @MattЭллен I'm promoting hosting packages.

Comment: Sorry William, I mean are you trying to promote affordability or cheapness?

Comment: I think this discussion has proved the question is answerable.

Comment: ... versus [is] often abbreviated v. or v, vs. or vs [Wikipedia]

Comment: Without qualification, they mean pretty much the same thing IMHO. But I agree with @Raestloz's psychological point: affordable will be a better marketing phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence "Reliable, stable, secure, great support and of course not too expensive!" does not flow nearly as well as "Reliable, stable, secure, great support and of course affordable!" or even "Reliable, stable, secure, great support and of course great value!"

I think great value my be my personal choice because the repetition of great makes it seem even better, and it flows well.